# Google Maps keeps refreshing API when using FacetWP plugin

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, google-maps, facetwp

Wondering if anyone can help me get to the bottom of this issue. The Google map keeps refreshing a front.js.min file. I can see this in the network tab of the chrome developer tool at URL https://tipperary.com/listings/

Does anyone have any experience in the FacetWP plugin that might have come across this issue before? It seems to be an issue with AJAX refreshing every time there is a listing template loaded.

You can see the page constantly refresh when loaded. There are 238 listings on this page. If you hold out for them to load the map functionality seems to work ok. I'd really appreciate anyone who has experience in JS, AJAX, or FacetWP's input.

Thanks in advance. If you need any more info on code snippets please let me know but I think the answer will be viewable using the chrome developer tools.

Happy to buy many coffees for anyone who can help me solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I checked your site and it appears you are loading Google Maps API multiple times. Could you please revisit your implementation and try to remove it and check if it resolves your problem?

Comment: Hi Rafon, thanks a million for your reponse. This is the problem, I can see it being loaded again but I've not a clue where that code is coming from on the site. The FacetWP plugin seems to use templates (Called facets) and I've went through the previous developers templates to see if it is calling the Google Map API in a template but it doesn't seem to be at all. The API code gets added to the FacetWP field in settings so that's taken away from me seeing where it gets added (unless it's been hardcoded into a template file someplace).

Comment: Have you tried contacting the plugin's developer?